# Reorder a array field when find from mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Consider the following code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/db');

const User = new Schema({
    user_id: { type: Number },
    medals: {
        type: [Number],
        get: (medals) => {
            return medals.slice().sort();
        }
    }
});

const UserModel = mongoose.model('User', User);

const record = new UserModel();
record.medals = [1, 3, 2];
record.user_id = 666;

record.save(function(err) {
    UserModel.findOne({ user_id: 666 }, function(err, user) {
        console.log(user.medals)
        // user.medals: [1, 2, 3] 
        console.log(user);
        // user: { user_id: 666, medals: [1, 3, 2] }
    });
});
```

I define a `User` Schema with two fields: `user_id` and `medals`.

### What I want to do

Reorder the `medals` field when I call `find` or `findOne`.

### What I cannot do

1. reorder the `medals` field in a setter function
2. reorder the `medals` field before saving to database
3. reorder the `medals` field after calling `find` or `findOne`

### How I try

I defined a getter method from `medals` field. In the getter function, I sort the `medals` array and return the sorted array.

### What's wrong

In above code snippet, I save a user whose medals is `[1, 3, 2]` to the database.

When I print `user.medals`, It is `[1, 2, 3]`. It is sorted. This is right.

But when I print `user` object, It's `medals` is `[1, 3, 2]` which is unsorted.

### Question

How to reorder the `medals` field so that when I print `user`, It's value is `{ user_id: 666, medals: [1, 2, 3] }`?

Forgive my poor English. Any help to improve my question description is welcome!

Comment: Nice question structure)